# Static files 404 in production

Tags: django

None of my static files are loading after deploying my app. When I check in the dev tools they're all 404.

I ran `python3 manage.py collectstatic`

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/srv/example/static/'
```

My static folder has the following permissions and ownership:

`drwxr-xr-x  8 root root     4096 Nov 17 23:28 static`

My `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.conf`:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-access.log combined

       WSGIDaemonProcess example processes=2 threads=25 python-ho>
       WSGIProcessGroup example
       WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/example/example/wsgi.py

      Alias /robots.txt /srv/example/static/robots.txt
      Alias /favicon.ico /srv/example/static/favicon.ico
      Alias /static /srv/example/static/
      Alias /media /srv/example/media/

      <Directory /srv/example/example>
          <Files wsgi.py>
              Require all granted
          </Files>
      </Directory>

      <Directory /srv/example/static>
          Require all granted
      </Directory>

      <Directory /srv/example/media>
          Require all granted
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does the apache log show the inbound request returning a 404?

Comment: Yes they are 404 in my `access.log` too

Comment: Do you think this is a coding problem with your app? if its a configuration problem, maybe it should be transferred to `serverfault`?

Answer (score 0):

1. did you check after "collectstatic" that the files are in the folder /static/?
2. I am not sure if it matters ... but my Alias has no slash at the end:

   Alias /static /.../...../static

Comment: My static files are in the folder and I tried removing the trailing slashes with no luck

Comment: /static/ folder should belong to group www-data

Comment: Just the group or both user and group? Because I now have it as both and still 404

Comment: www-data is the group Apache belongs to. If all folders in the path belong to group www-data and have read access for group it should work (if there is not another issue)